# Evaluating multiple conditions in if-then-else block in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to create a new column in a Pandas DataFrame by evaluating multiple conditions in an if-then-else block.

```
if events.hour <= 6:
    events['time_slice'] = 'night'
elif events.hour <= 12:
    events['time_slice'] = 'morning'
elif events.hour <= 18:
    events['time_slice'] = 'afternoon'
elif events.hour <= 23:
    events['time_slice'] = 'evening'
```

When I run this, I get the error below:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

So I tried to solve this by adding the any statement like shown below:

```
if (events.hour <= 6).any():
    events['time_slice'] = 'night'
elif (events.hour <= 12).any():
    events['time_slice'] = 'morning'
elif (events.hour <= 18).any():
    events['time_slice'] = 'afternoon'
elif (events.hour <= 23).any():
    events['time_slice'] = 'evening'
```

Now I do not get any error, but when I check the unique values of time_slice, it only shows 'night'

```
np.unique(events.time_slice)
```

> array(['night'], dtype=object)

How can I solve this, because my data contains samples that should get 'morning', 'afternoon' or 'evening'. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [pd.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method in order to categorize your data:

Demo:

```
In [66]: events = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 23, 10), columns=['hour'])

In [67]: events
Out[67]:
   hour
0     5
1    17
2    12
3     2
4    20
5    22
6    20
7    11
8    14
9     8

In [71]: events['time_slice'] = pd.cut(events.hour, bins=[-1, 6, 12, 18, 23], labels=['night','morning','afternoon','evening'])

In [72]: events
Out[72]:
   hour time_slice
0     5      night
1    17  afternoon
2    12    morning
3     2      night
4    20    evening
5    22    evening
6    20    evening
7    11    morning
8    14  afternoon
9     8    morning
```

Comment: Maybe the first bin would be `-1` because if the entry is `0`, it might make it NaN?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function:

```
def time_slice(hour):
    if hour <= 6:
        return 'night'
    elif hour <= 12:
        return 'morning'
    elif hour <= 18:
        return 'afternoon'
    elif hour <= 23:
        return 'evening'
```

then `events['time_slice'] = events.hour.apply(time_slice)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy approach to it -

```
tags = ['night','morning','afternoon','evening']
events['time_slice'] = np.take(tags,((events.hour.values-1)//6).clip(min=0))
```

Sample run -

```
In [130]: events
Out[130]: 
   hour time_slice
0     0      night
1     8    morning
2    16  afternoon
3    20    evening
4     2      night
5    14  afternoon
6     7    morning
7    18  afternoon
8     8    morning
9    22    evening
```

Comment: `((events.hour.values-1)//6).clip(min=0)` - this is pretty smart

Comment: @MaxU I guess so, but works for regular intervals only.